# Constant Sample Variance

Tags: probability, statistics

If the sample variance $S^2$ is constant, can we say the population is constant? If so, how to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are iid random variables.  Given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a positive probability that $X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are so close to $X_1$ that the sample variance is less than $\epsilon$.  So if the sample variance is almost surely constant, that constant must be $0$.  But the only way the sample variance can be $0$ is that
all $X_i$ are with probability $1$ equal to the mean.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you very much. My classmate told me another way to do this. Assume X can take two values a and b. If every $X_i$ takes a, then $S^2$ is 0. If the first n-1 $X_i$ takes a and the last takes b, $S^2$ would be positive, which contradicts.